# How to parse JSON data from syslog with fluentd?

Tags: parsing, elasticsearch, logging, fluentd, rsyslog

My custom rsyslog template:

```
template(name="outfmt" type="list" option.jsonf="on") {
         property(outname="@timestamp"
                  name="timereported" 
                  dateFormat="rfc3339" format="jsonf")
         property(outname="host"
                  name="hostname" format="jsonf")
         property(outname="severity"
                  name="syslogseverity-text" caseConversion="upper" format="jsonf")
         property(outname="facility"
                  name="syslogfacility-text" format="jsonf")
         property(outname="syslog-tag"
                  name="syslogtag" format="jsonf")
         property(outname="source"
                  name="app-name" format="jsonf")
         property(outname="message"
                  name="msg" format="jsonf")

     }
```

My rsyslog example output:

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2018-03-01T01:00:00+00:00",
  "host": "172.20.245.8",
  "severity": "DEBUG",
  "facility": "local4",
  "syslog-tag": "app[1666]",
  "source": "app",
  "message": " this is my syslog message"
}
```

How can I parse this log with fluentd and send to elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can receive logs directly in elasticsearch (without even having to format them to json) through the [syslog plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-syslog.html). This probably would be the most straightforward solution to your problem.

If for some reason u need to use some kind of log aggregator, I personally would not recommend fluentd, as it *can* bring unecessary complexity with it.

But you could use logstash which is supported by elasticsearch and you can find plenty of [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/de/blog/how-to-centralize-logs-with-rsyslog-logstash-and-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-14-04) about it.